# Creating archive after upgrading Xcode to 14.0 cause error inside flutter plugging signing requires a development team

Tags: xcode, flutter

I'm unable to create an archive after upgrading Xcode to 14.0

- Xcode: 14.0
- IOS Deployment target: 15.0
- Minimum Deployment: 15.0

[image: Error log]

Already tried by allowing automatic signing and the development team

[image]

Comment: You can create your own account for it then go back sign in the account youve created then thats all

Comment: I already tried that solution but doesn't work.  @ArbiterChil

Answer (score 0):

Don't forgot to select **All**  and **Automatically manage signing**

- Select your Development team in all packages
- Clean build folder and rebuild the archive.
- Issue solved

[image]